# Which server and hosting for streaming video and images?

Tags: webserver, shared-hosting, streaming, video-hosting

We are looking for suggestions on which hosting and server to use for our app that allows us to upload content (images/videos) which is viewed by our users on their smartphones. The videos are in MP4 format and 10 seconds on average to a minute long.

This is the first time we've done something like this and we need suggestions on a which hosting to use and also which dedicated server

We are planning on using a CDN like Amazon Cloudfront to deliver the multimedia so we dont have to worry about using a lot of server resources streaming the videos or images.

The server will be mainly used to

- Upload and store images and videos
- Host a mysql database
- Be used as a backend (PHP)
- Upload the content to the CDN as required

I'm thinking of this set up for the server

- Ubuntu
- nginx
- PHP 7
- Mysql 5.7

I have a $150/month budget for a server. This is the first time I've done something like this so suggestions are welcome and apperciated.

We had a beta test that had thousands of users download our app so we believe we will initially have about 25,000 users and double that by month two.

Most of our users are from North America and Europe